# ASP.NET core RC1 to 1.0.0 migration errors

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to migrate my asp.net core 1.0.0 RC1 application to final 1.0.0 and with the help of other posts I managed to change all references from RC1 to final 1.0.0
But still there are couple of errors remains which I cant find suitable replacement methods or references

```
app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
```

> *Error    CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseIISPlatformHandler' and no extension method
>   'UseIISPlatformHandler' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0"` in project.json

```
services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

> *Error    CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFramework' and no extension method 'AddEntityFramework'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have  `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0", "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",` in project.json

Please could anyone help me to resolve these?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend create a new web application with individual user accounts and then compare the new project to your current one to see what has changed. in the latest you will get a Program.cs file and the IIS integration goes there rather than in startup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For first issue,

remove `app.UseIISPlatformHandler` line and add `UseIISIntegration()` in Main method like below-

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()    // Replaces call to UseIISPlatformHandler
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();


            host.Run();
        }
```

For second issue,

Use `services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` instead of `services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()`

**References:**

Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0 
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html

Migrating from ASP.NET Core RC2 to ASP.NET Core 1.0
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc2-to-rtm.html

See if this helps.